# What are the proper scopes/indices to help to make scoped finds more performant through rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, optimization, scope

I have a relatively large 4-deep relational data setup like this:

```
ClientApplication         has_many => ClientApplicationVersions
ClientApplicationVersions has_many => CloudLogs
CloudLogs                 has_many => Logs
```

`client_applications`: (potentially 1,000's of records)
   - `...`
   - `account_id`
   - `public_key`
   - `deleted_at`

`client_application_versions`: (potentially 10,000's of records)
   - `...`
   - `client_application_id`
   - `public_key`
   - `deleted_at`

`cloud_logs`: (potentially 1,000,000's of records)
   - ...
   - `client_application_version_id`
   - `public_key`
   - `deleted_at`

`logs`: (potentially 1,000,000,000's of records) 
   - `...`
   - `cloud_log_id`
   - `public_key`
   - `time_stamp`
   - `deleted_at`

---

I am still in development so the structure and setup is not set in stone, but I hope it is setup ok. Using Rails 3.2.11 and InnoDB MySQL. The database is currently filled with a small (compared to the eventual db size) set of data (`logs` only has 500,000 rows) I have 4 scoped queries, 3 of which are problematic, to retrieve logs.

1. Grab first page of logs, ordered by timestamp, limited by `account_id`, `client_application.public_key`, `client_application_version.public_key` (Over 100 seconds)
2. Grab first page of logs, ordered by timestamp, limited by `account_id`, `client_application.public_key` (Over 100 seconds)
3. Grab first page of logs, ordered by timestamp, limited by `account_id` (Over 100 seconds)
4. Grab first page of logs, ordered by timestamp (~2 seconds)

---

I am using rails scopes to help make these calls:

```
  scope :account_id, proc {|account_id| joins(:client_application).where("client_applications.account_id = ?", account_id) }
  scope :client_application_key, proc {|client_application_key| joins(:client_application).where("client_applications.public_key = ?", client_application_key) }
  scope :client_application_version_key, proc {|client_application_version_key| joins(:client_application_version).where("client_application_versions.public_key = ?", client_application_version_key) }

  default_scope order('logs.timestamp DESC')
```

I have indices on each table on `public_key`. I have several indices on the `logs` table including the one that the optimizer prefers to use (`index_logs_on_cloud_log_id`), but the queries are still taking eons to run.

---

Here is how I am calling the method in `rails console`:

```
Log.account_id(1).client_application_key('p0kZudG0').client_application_version_key('0HgoJRyE').page(1)
```

... here is what rails turns it into:

```
SELECT `logs`.* FROM `logs` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` ON `cloud_logs`.`id` = `logs`.`cloud_log_id` INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` ON `client_application_versions`.`id` = `cloud_logs`.`client_application_version_id` INNER JOIN `client_applications` ON `client_applications`.`id` = `client_application_versions`.`client_application_id` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` `cloud_logs_logs_join` ON `cloud_logs_logs_join`.`id` = `logs`.`cloud_log_id` INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` `client_application_versions_logs` ON `client_application_versions_logs`.`id` = `cloud_logs_logs_join`.`client_application_version_id` WHERE (logs.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (client_applications.account_id = 1) AND (client_applications.public_key = 'p0kZudG0') AND (client_application_versions.public_key = '0HgoJRyE') ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

... and here is the EXPLAIN statement for that query.

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                            | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                         | key                                               | key_len | ref                                                                    | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client_application_versions      | ref    | PRIMARY,index_client_application_versions_on_client_application_id,index_client_application_versions_on_public_key                                    | index_client_application_versions_on_public_key   | 768     | const                                                                  |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client_applications              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_client_applications_on_account_id,index_client_applications_on_public_key                                                               | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | cloudlog_production.client_application_versions.client_application_id  |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cloud_logs                       | ref    | PRIMARY,index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id                                                                                             | index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id | 5       | cloudlog_production.client_application_versions.id                     |  481 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cloud_logs_logs_join             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | cloudlog_production.cloud_logs.id                                      |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client_application_versions_logs | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | cloudlog_production.cloud_logs_logs_join.client_application_version_id |    1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs                             | ref    | index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at_and_timestamp,index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at,index_logs_on_cloud_log_id,index_logs_on_deleted_at | index_logs_on_cloud_log_id                        | 5       | cloudlog_production.cloud_logs.id                                      |    4 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

---

This question has 3 parts to it:

1. Can I optimize my DB with additional indices to help these type of join-dependent sort queries become more performant?
2. Can I optimize the rails code to help this type of `find` run in a more performant way?
3. Am I simply approaching this scoped find the wrong way for large datasets?

**UPDATE 1/24/12**
As suggested by Geoff and J_MCCaffrey in the answers, I have split the query up into 3 different sections to try and isolate the problem. As expected, it is a problem dealing with the largest table. The MYSQL optimizer handles this differently by using different indices, but the delay persists. Here is the EXPLAIN for this approach.

```
ClientApplication.find_by_account_id_and_public_key(1, 'p0kZudG0').versions.select{|cav| cav.public_key = '0HgoJRyE'}.first.logs.page(2)
  ClientApplication Load (165.9ms)  SELECT `client_applications`.* FROM `client_applications` WHERE `client_applications`.`account_id` = 1 AND `client_applications`.`public_key` = 'p0kZudG0' AND (client_applications.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY client_applications.id LIMIT 1
  ClientApplicationVersion Load (105.1ms)  SELECT `client_application_versions`.* FROM `client_application_versions` WHERE `client_application_versions`.`client_application_id` = 3 AND (client_application_versions.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY client_application_versions.created_at DESC, client_application_versions.id DESC
  Log Load (57295.0ms)  SELECT `logs`.* FROM `logs` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` ON `logs`.`cloud_log_id` = `cloud_logs`.`id` WHERE `cloud_logs`.`client_application_version_id` = 49 AND (logs.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (cloud_logs.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC, cloud_logs.received_at DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
  EXPLAIN (214.5ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `logs`.* FROM `logs` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` ON `logs`.`cloud_log_id` = `cloud_logs`.`id` WHERE `cloud_logs`.`client_application_version_id` = 49 AND (logs.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (cloud_logs.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC, cloud_logs.received_at DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `logs`.* FROM `logs` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` ON `logs`.`cloud_log_id` = `cloud_logs`.`id` WHERE `cloud_logs`.`client_application_version_id` = 49 AND (logs.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (cloud_logs.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC, cloud_logs.received_at DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type        | possible_keys                                                                                                                                         | key                                                                              | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra                                                                                                                                           |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cloud_logs | index_merge | PRIMARY,index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id,index_cloud_logs_on_deleted_at                                                              | index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id,index_cloud_logs_on_deleted_at | 5,9     | NULL                              | 1874 | Using intersect(index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id,index_cloud_logs_on_deleted_at); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs       | ref         | index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at_and_timestamp,index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at,index_logs_on_cloud_log_id,index_logs_on_deleted_at | index_logs_on_cloud_log_id                                                       | 5       | cloudlog_production.cloud_logs.id |    4 | Using where                                                                                                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**UPDATE 1/25/12**
Here are the indices for all relevant tables:

```
CLIENT_APPLICATIONS:
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_client_applications_on_key` (`key`),
  KEY `index_client_applications_on_account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `index_client_applications_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_client_applications_on_public_key` (`public_key`)

CLIENT_APPLICATION_VERSIONS:
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `index_client_application_versions_on_client_application_id` (`client_application_id`),
  KEY `index_client_application_versions_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_client_application_versions_on_public_key` (`public_key`)

CLOUD_LOGS:
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_api_client_version_id` (`api_client_version_id`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_client_application_version_id` (`client_application_version_id`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_public_key` (`public_key`),
  KEY `index_cloud_logs_on_received_at` (`received_at`)

LOGS:
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_class_name` (`class_name`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at_and_timestamp` (`cloud_log_id`,`deleted_at`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at` (`cloud_log_id`,`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_cloud_log_id` (`cloud_log_id`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_file_name` (`file_name`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_method_name` (`method_name`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_public_key` (`public_key`),
  KEY `index_logs_on_timestamp` USING BTREE (`timestamp`)
```

Comment: When you are actually calling the data you should call your scope and then "find_each", check out the method AR's API doc. It loads your data in batches (default: 1000). This keeps AR from loading all your data into memory at the same time.

Comment: @cpuguy83 is that any different from using the LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 that I have now to only load a limited subset of records?

Comment: @coneybeare, up and favourite votes are _not_ a reason to re-open a question... the last is however.

Comment: `Using filesort` in your EXPLAIN indicates that there are either TEXT /BLOB columns in one of the joined tables or your MySQL's memory settings are too conservative. You want to get rid of that

Comment: I have 2 text fields in the whole DB, but neither of them are part of the ordering or condition clauses here. Can you explain your comment a bit further, perhaps in it's own answer?

Comment: That's not what file sort means http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: Have you looked into using Stored Procedures? It's great for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I would like to avoid it as Rails doesn't have great support for Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this a possible solution to my own question, in the hopes that a better answer will come by. Currently, the DB is setup completely and by-the-book relational.

```
ClientApplication         has_many => ClientApplicationVersions
ClientApplicationVersions has_many => CloudLogs
CloudLogs                 has_many => Logs
```

This means that when I need to find Logs that belong to a Client Application, I have to do 3 extra joins just to get it. By introducing some `foreign_key` denormalization to the Logs table, I can skip all the joins:

```
ClientApplication         has_many => ClientApplicationVersions
ClientApplication         has_many => Logs
ClientApplicationVersions has_many => CloudLogs
ClientApplicationVersions has_many => Logs
CloudLogs                 has_many => Logs
```

The end result is that I would have a few extra columns in my Logs table: `client_application_key`, `client_application_version_key`, and `cloud_log_key`.

Although I risk inconsistent data, I can avoid the 3 joins here that are helping to kill the performance of the queries. Somebody please talk me out of this.

Comment: I tried every solution on this page, and found this to be the only solution which got me in the ms range, not seconds. IDs and keys rarely if ever change, so denormalization was the best approach for this type of find.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying it with a better structure, the query looks like this (already re-arranged)

```
SELECT
  `logs`.*
FROM
  `logs` as l
  INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` as cl1
    ON
      cl1.id = l.cloud_log_id
  INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` as cl2
    ON
      cl2.id = l.cloud_log_id
  INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` as cav1
    ON
      cav1.id = cl1.client_application_version_id
  INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` as cav2
    ON
      cav2.id = cl2.client_application_version_id
  INNER JOIN `client_applications` as ca
    ON
      ca.id = cav1.client_application_id
WHERE
  (l.deleted_at IS NULL)
    AND
  (ca.account_id = 1)
    AND
  (ca.public_key = 'p0kZudG0')
    AND
  (cav.public_key = '0HgoJRyE')
ORDER BY
  logs.timestamp DESC
LIMIT
  0, 100
```

When looking at cav1/cl1 and cav2/cl2 one can see, that cav2 and cl2 are never used.
There is no filter applied to them apart from the ON statement.

Therefore cav1 is linked to the correct accoutn, cav2 is not linked to any account, and rather contains all matching accounts.
This is no problem for the result of the query, but for the size of the join buffer.

Removing the joins (and ON-parts of them) yields:

```
SELECT
  `logs`.*
FROM
  `logs` as l
  INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` as cl1
    ON
      cl1.id = l.cloud_log_id
--  INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` as cl2
--    ON
--      cl2.id = l.cloud_log_id
  INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` as cav1 use index for join (`index_cavs_on_client_application_id_and_public_key`)
    ON
      cav1.id = cl1.client_application_version_id
        AND
      cav1.public_key = '0HgoJRyE'

--  INNER JOIN `client_application_versions` as cav2
--    ON
--      cav2.id = cl2.client_application_version_id
  INNER JOIN `client_applications` as ca
    ON
      ca.id = cav1.client_application_id
WHERE
  (l.deleted_at IS NULL)
    AND
  (ca.account_id = 1)
    AND
  (ca.public_key = 'p0kZudG0')
ORDER BY
  logs.timestamp DESC
LIMIT
  0, 100
```

This one should be faster.

Packing this into something useable in console (assuming correct table relations and meta_where):

```
Log.where(:deleted_at.ne => nil).order("logs.timestamp desc").joins(:cloud_logs) & \
CloudLog.joins(:client_application_versions) & \
ClientApplicationVersion.where(:public_key => '0HgoJRyE').joins(:client_applications) & \
ClientApplication.where(:public_key => 'p0kZudG0', :account_id => 1)
```

Since i can't reproduce this here, you might have to try for yourself (or add a to_sql to the end)
And also add an explain to the shortened query above.

The results might be interesting.

update:
after seeing the result and definitions (comments below):

try adding a key:

```
alter table client_application_versions add key (`client_application_id`, `public_key`);
```

this should prevent the filesort and speed things up.

edit:
updated query to hint mysql about the key.

Comment: Running it this way as SQL was definitely an improvement. It runs between 36 and 45 seconds: https://gist.github.com/4635180 I could not get it to run like this using Rails c though... only find_by_sql

Comment: can you provide the explain for the reduced query?

Comment: ah, did not notice at first.  within the gist you removed the comment signs `--`. please either remove the lines or re-add the comment signs. the explain for the resulting query ist the helpful one

Comment: Oh, I didn't know those were comment signs! Let me run it again, brb

Comment: can you provide the table definitions for cloud_logs, client_application_versions and client_applications? `show create table cloud_logs;` `show create table client_application_versions;` `show create table client_applications;` ... edit: the lower part with the keys would be enough

Comment: Here are the current index definitions for all relevant tables: https://gist.github.com/4635448

Comment: added an alter table above

Comment: The optimizer still chooses not to use the new index: https://gist.github.com/4636692

Comment: you can hint mysql to use those. see above

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my Rails optimization experience has all been with PostgreSQL, so most of it probably doesn't apply. I do have a couple of suggestions that will probably be applicable, though:

Try using `joins` instead of `includes` in your scopes - `includes` is used to trigger eager loading - it's entirely possible that some of the slowdown you're seeing is unneeded models being loaded. Even if it isn't, using `joins` instead should produce a more readable query - it's `includes` that's aliasing all your columns as 't2_r8', and so on.

Also, you'll want to make sure that any columns that might be filtered are indexed - generally speaking, columns that end in `_id` are potentially going to be referenced in this way, and should probably be indexed, as well as any you specifically filter by in the scopes (like `client_application_version_key`)

Comment: For your second point, you are saying they should be combined indices right? Like client_application_id_and_public_key? They already each have indices on the public_key columns.

Comment: Ah, no, I misread the question slightly - those are the ones I meant. I don't actually know if combining the indicies will help - that feels a bit too database-specific.

Comment: I swapped the includes out to joins and only saved a couple of seconds, but it makes the sql more readable. I updated the sql and explain in the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer each of your questions:

1. Certainly! Anything you are searching on should probably be indexed. If it's not indexed, you have to do a full table scan. On top of the association IDs which would have been created when you did your initial migration if you used the `references` function in `create_table`, you are searching on at least the following:

   - logs.timestamp
   - client_application_versions.public_key
   - client_applications.public_key
   - logs.deleted_at

   These should probably all be indexed. And of course, if you didn't use `references` when defining your association foreign keys, then add them as well. There is of course a trade off with indices. They are like magic for reads, but they may slow down your writes significantly. The degree to which they slow you down or speed you up is probably heavily database dependent too.
2. I don't think so. Your rails code looks about right to me. The only comment I have is that `scope` is really just a shorthand way of defining a function. I think it would be easier to read if you just defined the function directly:

   ```
   self.account_id(account_id)
     joins(:client_application).where("client_applications.account_id = ?", account_id)
   end
   ```
3. Perhaps! Unfortunately, this is not an easy question to answer because it really is dependent on what the data looks like. Do you really need billions of logs in the same database table? Is there some way to naturally break up the data perhaps into different tables with the same schema? You might also want to research database sharding.

I hope that helps.

**Edit:**

Why are you doing the query in the direction of most pain?  Have you tried turning it around from:

```
Log.account_id(1).client_application_key('p0kZudG0').client_application_version_key('0HgoJRyE').page(1)
```

To something like this:

```
ClientApplication.find_all_by_account_id(1).where(public_key: 'p0kZudG0').joins(:client_application_version).where("client_application_versions.public_key=?",'0HgoJRyE').logs.page(1)
```

You should define some scopes to make that more readable, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: 1) So I already have indices on all the ones you mentioned, as shown in the EXPLAIN, yet the query is still running a filesort  2) I am also using the has_scope gem so I dont mind the scope syntax    3) A "log" is the lowest level I can break this model down to. Over time I can probably put older logs in a different table, but there will definitely be a log of current logs too, and it shouldn't be this slow for only 500k.

Comment: Ah yes. I don't see logs.timestamps though which is probably an important one.

Comment: I have the combined ones though, including cloud_log_id_and_timestamp, so if the mysql query optimizer is choosing to use the cloud_log_id one and not the combined one, I think that the root of the problem lies elsewhere. I will try it though, but I don't expect it to be any different.

Comment: Looks like I actually already do have an index on timestamp alone, so MYSQL is just choosing not to use it. RE your edit about "pain", I am unclear as to why you think that would be faster? It seems to me that you are now making 3 different DB calls instead of one.

Comment: Give it a try. I think it will only be one query (once you get the syntax right), but making more calls isn't necessarily a bad thing especially if it avoids joining in more table rows you don't need.

Comment: Well, Arel compiles this down to the same query if I rework it into Arel style. Otherwise, this approach takes 3 queries (one to get the client_application, one to get it's versions, then a ruby .select to get the right one, then another to get the LOGS) at 98 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into a problem with the performance of a query like this, I look at what Rails is doing, and figure out if there is a better way to get what I want. Most of the time the Rails queries will be just fine, but sometimes you realize you can get what you need a faster/cleaner way.

You might be able to get what you want in 2 queries, but I would start by breaking out the joins and seeing how the query performs if you feed in the data you were getting from the joins.

Have you tested the results without the limit and offset? I would want to rule out the sorting and limiting part, and observe the performance. I've seen big issues with limit and offset before, and there are ways to tune how mysql can handle the sorting in memory instead of using a temp table and filesort as yours is currently doing.

**EDIT**

You could query for the ids first, then query for all columns based on the ids.

SELECT `logs`.id FROM `logs` INNER JOIN `cloud_logs` ON `logs`.`cloud_log_id` = `cloud_logs`.`id` WHERE `cloud_logs`.`client_application_version_id` = 49 AND (logs.deleted_at IS NULL) 
AND (cloud_logs.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC limit 100

Is that query fast? (it should be able to get the ids from the index without scanning the table)
A more invasive change might be to partition your data at the DB level, but I think it's too early to suggest that.

Comment: w/o LIMIT OFFSET it is 57 seconds. Taking out the ORDER is near instantaneous. I can't really do either in production as there will be thousands of returned rows without the pagination, and the model needs to be ordered by the most recent.

Comment: I tried breaking it up as Geoff mentioned before, the logs fetch is still the problem. https://gist.github.com/4621738 It is strangely running around 60 seconds this morning, but all previous identical test had it running at ~100 seconds.

Comment: awesome!  Now you've answered the question about whether this is a Rails scoping problem. It would appear that it is not a Rails issue, but rather an issue with how to optimize Mysql when using LIMIT and OFFSET with lots of data. Now you can search for that with the appropriate mysql keywords.
These may be good starts:
http://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql
http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: The edited query you presented is missing a few of the key elements and joins, notably the client_application_version.public_key and client_application.account_id and client_application.public_key. Do you think the strategy would still work with the extra joins and WHERE fields?

Comment: I was mostly helping to answer your question about what Rails is responsible for, and how to determine where the problem lies. I think you were able to get past Rails, by removing the limit and offset, and now you can dig into other ways to deal with this common problem. (which are not related to scopes/indices or Rails)
Were you able to get better direction through the links I provided? (or by digging into Mysql specific tuning for this?)

Answer (score 0):

Your index is defined incorrectly `index_logs_on_cloud_log_id_and_deleted_at_and_timestamp`

The part of your queries that is taking too long is the `order by` clause, and you are ordering by `timestamp` but the `timestamp` is the last key of your index. In MySQL, later keys in an index will not be used to optimize the `order by` unless the previous keys are constants in the `where` clause. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

For starters, just create an index on `timestamp` and see if that speeds your queries.

Comment: This is interesting. I already have an index on timestamp and the optimizer is choosing not to use it. Here are the indices: http://cloud.coneybeare.net/MR6s  If I were to rearrange the order of the incorrect index above, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit hard, because in order to have performance you'll have to sacrifice readability, or the other way round. So, answering your questions:

1. Indexes are an idea, but it's success might vary depending of table sizes and how often and on which combination of keys the queries run. But it seems to me you query the same thing, you just order it differently. So... why not use DB views? Their implementation in rails sucks, but it is usable: https://github.com/eladmeidar/PlainViews
2. (forgetting whether you are going with my view suggestion) yes, you can. Don't use scopes. ARel has made them practically obsolete, and in your example most definitely, because you can be as descriptive resorting only to ARel. And just another thing: don't write SQL with ARel. You will miss a lot of goodies like renaming tables to adapt to joins and stuff, which can mess with your indexes. Something more like this:

   ```
   YourObject.joins(:client_application).
              where(ClientApplication.arel_table[:public_key].eq(client_application_key))
   ```
3. depends where you are going to use it. If the query is core to your application functionality then you should investigate more in alternative ways of making it more performant. For instance, the DBs provide a lot of features the web frameworks (and particularly Rails) don't advocate, like the mentioned views or stored procedures. How can you leverage that and maintain you code readability is the daily challenge of our fellow developers.

But I still have a question: Why didn't you use MongoDB? http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1016320617/mongodb-is-web-scale

Comment: and by the way, not going full-ARel ass mentioned in point 2 was maybe the reason why some inner joins got repeated in your first try (just read scones answer more thoroughly).